# Sharing a common dll between binaries in different directories

Tags: dll

I have multiple dll, living in different subdirectories, which depend on another 3rd party dll called common.dll. I would like to set up those dlls so that they know where to find common.dll without making common.dll visible to other programs to avoid clashes.

For example:

- foo/bar.dll
- foo/bar/fubar.dll
- common/common.dll

With both bar.dll and fubar.dll depending on common.dll

I have the following constraints:

- While I have complete control on the dlls, I don't have control of the calling executable, so modifying PATH is not an option.
- it has to work on every windows from XP up to 7
- I cannot install the common.dll in a "known" location used by windows
- modifying the dlls code to set up paths through an API is not desirable

IOW, something like unix rpath + ORIGIN on my dlls would be the ideal solution

I was hoping that using manifest could help, but it looks very complicated or not availble for windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that that you're using windows a common approach I use is to create a symbolic link to the physical location of the file, in some directory. Then the the caller only has to know some 'known directory' where you put the link and windows magically redirects to the correct file...

real file `c:\blah\common\xxx.dll`

link : `c:\MyDir\xxx.dll`

now callers can use `c:\MyDir\xxx.dll` and they get to `c:\blah\common\xxx.dll`

syntax on windows is : `mklink  c:\MyDir\xxx.dll c:\blah\common\xxx.dll`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot install the common dll in a "known" directory.

Comment: Sorry, I've rephrased my answer - my words were confusing.